# Is the same wildcard SSL supported for multiple Parse Apps?

Tags: ssl, parse-platform, wildcard-subdomain

My organisation is utilising multiple Parse apps for different environments of our app. These each have individual subdomains: a.abc.co, b.abc.co, c.abc.co and d.abc.co.

I can buy a single wildcard SSL certificate for abc.co and this would work fine under a normal situation, however I'm worried that Parse will think something's going wrong if they see the same certificate being uploaded to multiple different Parse apps.

Does anybody know if Parse can support the same wildcard SSL certificate for multiple different Parse apps?

Note that the use of subdomains and abc.co is not subject to change (and of course abc.co is an example value). I haven't tried it because it's a tad too expensive for trial and error.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any reason why it wouldn't work, that's what wildcard SSL is for... why don't you just try it?

Comment: It's pretty expensive to "just try it". I don't think wildcard SSL was created to work with Parse apps - I'm asking if multiple Parse apps were made to work with the same wildcard certificate. You have to upload the certificate in the app's settings and I wouldn't be surprised if Parse thought something was going wrong because they were seeing the same certificate in multiple apps.

Comment: Sorry, I wrongly assumed you already had the wildcard SSL. I can't see how there would be a problem with Parse, you'll just upload the same SSL to each app you create. If you must have a definitive answer, try the Google Groups, Hector monitors them and should be able to help. The link is on the help page https://parse.com/help

Comment: As per your suggestion, I have created a replica question at Google Groups: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/parse-developers/WZyzkJps3MM

Answer (score 0):

**Wildcard SSL Certificate** will work fine with parse app.

**Wildcard SSLs** are designed in a way to support **multiple subdomains** hosted under single domain name.

If you will generate CSR with the common name as ***.abc.co** so it will secure all the subdomains like **mail.abc.co, api.abc.co, www.abc.co etc.**